# Android google maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing an android application using google maps API V2, the application crashed and I have this error.

```
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown
Source) 06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
Source) 06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
com.its.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 06-04
12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):  at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-04 12:26:31.980: E/AndroidRuntime(16726):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
```

I can display the map with this code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

but when I try to add a marker with this code, the application crash

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {

            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have added the libraries of Google service.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.its.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-SDK
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.its.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.its.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.its.android.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.its.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxx" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way:

From the activity layout file you do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

So you define a map fragment in your xml file.

From the other hand you are trying to create an instance of the map fragment from code and adding it manualy:

```
 SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

So basically you are adding the map fragment twice, and they are not connected one to another.

Another thing you should do is to remove this line:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

it's a API V1 permission and has nothing to do with API V2.

Comment: I see but this is working for me, it crash when I try to add a marker (the second code)

Comment: strange, for what I know this should not make the app crash, but never the less it's great it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add google play services project as a library instead of putting jar file inside libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

import google-play-services_lib as a project and while importing select copy to workspace

Have you added all these permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="YOUR PACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOUR PACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: k have you added it in library also? and you need to add android-support-v4.jar to external jars

Comment: you imported google-play-services_lib as a project to your work space right after that right click on your project-properties-android-right hand side under library add and select google-play-services_lib. and also as i said you need to add android-support-v4.jar to external jars this is needed to use supportfragment

Comment: Exactly.. the library "google-play-services_lib" you're talking about is just the "google-play-services_lib.jar" file or all the folder.. because I have imported the folder in my workspace but In project-properties I've add just the .jar file right!

Comment: no its not the jar i think you are adding google-play-services_lib.jar which is inside google-play-services_lib\bin as a jar file. you have to add google-play-services_lib as a library project under android-library not as a jar

Comment: I have "android-support-v4.jar" in libs folder

Comment: you're right I was adding the jar .. I added the folder "google-play-services_lib" to the build path but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

import Google-play-services_lib from the android SDK

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{
    
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;  
    
    String[] mPlaceType=null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;
    
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        
        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);
        
        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);
        
        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);
        
        // Getting reference to the Spinner 
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);
        
        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        Button btnFind;
        
        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
        
        
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available
            
            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    
            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();
                    
            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            
            
            
            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            
            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   
                    
                    
                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];
                                        
                    
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyDX_1T5Cd826EVg9kIeJVdpWBadtTrBPcY");
                    
                    
                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   
                    
                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
                    
                    
                }
            });
            
        }       
        
    }
    
    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        Log.d("strUrl",""+strUrl);
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                
                

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();                

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }         

    
    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;
        
        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }
        
        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
            
            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
        
    }
    
    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        
        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
        
            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
        
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                
                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }
        
        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            
            
            // Clears all the existing markers 
            mGoogleMap.clear();
            
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            
                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                
                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
    
                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                
                
                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                
                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");
                
                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
                
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                
                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
    
                // Setting the title for the marker. 
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.snippet(vicinity);
    
                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);            
            
            }       
            
        }
        
    }
    
    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("mLatitude",""+mLatitude);
        Log.d("mLongitude",""+mLongitude);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity launched by launcher message?
Fragment needs a default initializer.

Try to run the second activity by intent.

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, [map activity].class);
startActivity(intent);
```